# What version of libpng is used in different versions of OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, libpng, opencv3.0, android

In my application I am reading .png images and doing some processing. The output with OpenCV 2.4.9 and OpenCV 3.0.0 (both for windows) are not bit exact. What may be the potential error. Is there any difference in libpng in both the versions which is causing the problem.

Also is there any possibility that the libs (e.g. libpng) or the version of libs is different in same version (say 2.4.9 or 3.0.0) of OpenCV for windows and OpenCV for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any difference in libpng in both the versions which is causing the problem.

You can check with `cv::getBuildInformation()` (see [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/34412/solved-opencv-libpng-version-mismatch/))

> Also is there any possibility that the libs (e.g. libpng) or the version of libs is different in same version (say 2.4.9 or 3.0.0) of OpenCV for windows and OpenCV for Android.

Yes, of course. OpenCV is dynamically linked to libPNG. The builds may even use the system libPNG (e.g. on Linux distributions) instead of the bundled libPNG.

Comment: getBuldInformation() tells you if you are using a different libpng version but doesn't explain any difference in libpng that could cause the problem.  The only thing I can recall is a change in scaling 16-bit samples down to 8-bit that was made more accurate in libpng-1.5, which could cause some samples to be off-by-one compared to libpng-1.4 and earlier.