# OpenCV 2.4.13.2 libpng vulnerable?

Tags: android, windows, android-security

Is the OpenCV 2.4.13.2 is libpng vulnerable? And how can I know the version of libpng in android studio windows?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31311159/5008845

Comment: still i cant view my libpng version. do you know if opencv 2.4.13.2 is vulnerable to libpng?

Comment: I don't know. Probably it's ok since it's a new release. You should use opencv 3 (release 3.3), though

Comment: If I use opencv 3.x . Some of my codes will not work.  So, Im hoping that my libpng version is acceptable to playstore